# Restify returns undefined is not a function in error object

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, restify

I have a below Restify custom error that is being thrown to my catch block of BlueBird Promise.

```
var test = function() {
  respObject = { hello: { world: 'aasas' } }; 
  throw new restify.errors.ServiceError(respObject, 422);
}
```

Then in ServiceError:

```
function ServiceError(respObject, statusCode) {
  restify.RestError.call(this, {
    restCode: 'ApiError',
    statusCode, statusCode,
    message: 'Api Error Occurred',
    constructorOpt: ServiceError,
    body: {
      message: 'Api Error Occurrede',
      errors: respObject.toJSON()
    }
  });

  this.name = 'CustomApiError';
}

util.inherits(ServiceError, restify.RestError);
restify.errors.ServiceError = ServiceError;
```

However on the calling function of `test()`:

```
test().catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

It's returning `undefined is not a function`. Is there a reason why it's not returning `err` object to above calling function under catch block?

Comment: What happens if you just `throw new Error('test')` in `test` - is it working properly? I don't understand how you can get `undefined is not a function`..

Comment: @AndreyPopov if I go `throw new Error('test')` I'm getting correct error object. It's just with Restify custom error that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was `respObject.toJSON()` that was causing `undefined is not a function` because `respObject` does not have `toJSON()` function :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with Restify, it's with your `test` function. You're calling `test().catch`, but `test()` doesn't return anything—i.e. it returns `undefined`. You're essentially calling `undefined.catch`, which doesn't exist.

If you want to call `catch` on the result of `test`, it needs to return a promise.

Comment: I don't know if that is right. It throws an exception which should end up on catch block. Even if you had return after exception, it would never end there

Comment: You don't have a `catch` block. That would look like this: `try { test(); } catch(err) { console.log(err); }` You're trying to call a function called `catch`, but you're not returning an object that has a `catch` function.

Comment: @Jordan so do I need to return after or before under test function?

Comment: That's hard to answer, because you haven't shown how you're actually using this code. You say you're using Bluebird promises, but there isn't any actual promise code in your question, and it's not clear what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: @Jordan I guess the interesting thing is that `throw new Error('test')` works fine and returns with error object correctly

Comment: Are you sure you're using Restify as intended? Glancing at the docs, they never `throw`, they call `next(new Error...)`.

Comment: @Jordan Yes I've tried `next(new restify.errors.ServiceError...` but I'm getting same results `undefined is not a function`

Comment: @Jordan I found the answer. It was `respObject.toJSON()` that was causing `undefined is not a function` because `respObject` does not have `toJSON()` function :)